# argsort on numpy.array as generator

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, generator

I am new in python, so may be I do something wrong. Let me first explain what I want.

I have a huge 1d `numpy.array` with some values and I need to know the indices of first n smallest values. I need them for later computation. Of course I can just do something like `ind = numpy.argsort(hugearray)[:n]`.

The problem is that beforehand I don't know how many indices I need, my computations are iterative and fetch one by one index til there are enough for computation.

Another thing is, that I want a lazy argsort to avoid creating new entire array of argsorted values and prevent unnesessary searching, so I thought of a generator. But truly I don't know how to do it with a numpy.array.

**UPD:** from hpaulj answer, I tried to create a generator:

```
def gargsort(arr):
    arr=arr.copy()
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        k = np.argmin(arr)
        arra[k] = np.iinfo(arr[k]).max
        yield k
```

May be it's possible to do it better?

Comment: mathematically, you have to sort all the array to know the smallest elements ?

Comment: `np.argpartition(hugearray, n)[:n]` will return the same indices, but in an unsorted order.  It's a partial ordering.  But there's no guarantee that it's faster than the full argsort.

Comment: @B.M. Yes, sure, I have to traverse the hugearray n times, with aprox. n * (len_array + 1 - n) accesses to array, if I search each time for argmin and then drop it from array.

Comment: @hpaulj the problem is, I don't know n yet. My stuff works so that I search for argmin in array, and if it doesn't fit some conditions, I must take the next "argsmallest"

Comment: And how much more expensive is `argsort` than `argmin`?  `argpartition` is the closest thing to the `n` smallest values for any `n` bigger than 1.

Comment: @hpaulj I don't understand the difference between `np.argpartition` and `np.argsort`.

Comment: argpartition = partial sort (but i have to admit the docs are a bit sparse on this part of the lib). It seems for example, that it's lazy by computation, but not by memory-usage. If your data is really huge and a full array is impossible, maybe you need to try dask's [topk](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.topk)

Comment: `argpartition` has linear complexity, therefore first `argpartition`ing, then `argsort`ing is O(n + k log(k)) which may be quite a bit faster than n log(n). Since you don't know k beforehand you could use an exponential growth strategy: Compute the first j, if they don't suffice compute the next 2j, then 4j and so on. if you need J in the end this will have complexity O((n + J log(J)) log(J)).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an iterative approach that appears to be faster than argsort, provided `n` isn't too large:

```
In [135]: arr = np.arange(200000)
In [136]: np.random.shuffle(arr)
In [137]: def foo(arr):
     ...:     arr=arr.copy()
     ...:     alist=[]
     ...:     for i in range(10):
     ...:         k=np.argmin(arr)
     ...:         alist.append(k)
     ...:         arr[k]=200000
     ...:     return alist
     ...: 
In [138]: foo(arr)
Out[138]: [176806, 180397, 139992, 151809, 59931, 59866, 130026, 191357, 84166, 130359]
In [139]: np.argsort(arr)[:10]
Out[139]: 
array([176806, 180397, 139992, 151809,  59931,  59866, 130026, 191357,
        84166, 130359], dtype=int32)
In [140]: timeit np.argsort(arr)[:10]
100 loops, best of 3: 15.8 ms per loop
In [141]: timeit foo(arr)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.69 ms per loop
```

(I'll comment later if needed).

Comment: ok, I tried to build a generator from your code, and for first few values it is okay. thanks! but maybe, it's still possible to do it better?

Comment: It depends strongly on the relative speed of `argmin` and `argsort`.  If you end up needing just a few of `argmin` steps, this loop is clearly better.  But for some larger `n` it's faster to sort the whole thing once and for all.  And as Panzer argues sorting in blocks with `argpartition` might help - in selected cases.